# Export and Import google-services.json to a new project in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an `Android app` and I use`FCM Push Notification` . I have created a new `Firebase` account and I want to use it instead of the old one . So how can I Export and Import `Google-services.json` to a new project in `Firebase` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `google-services.json` contains information about your Firebase project and the  apps you've defined in that project.

If you've created a new project and want to use that with an existing app, you will need to add the app to the new project. After doing that, you will have to download the `google-services.json` from the new project, and add it to your Android app (replacing the `google-services.json` from the old project). From that point on your app will be connected to the new project.

Comment: Thanks for reply I will try it